# Parallel kernel configuration settings missing on MacBook ARM

Tags: parallelization, mac-os-x

```
$Version
(* 12.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 8, 2021) *)
```

In the preferences panel, the parallel kernel settings are missing.

[image]

Evaluating

```
Parallel`Palette`tabPreferences[]
(* tabPreferences[] *)
```

Has anyone else experienced this problem? Any ideas on how to identify the issue and fix it?

Comment: Works fine on 13.0.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 28, 2022)